# How to apply a CSS height setting to all child elements?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to put an iframe in Wordpress, but I couldn't give it the same height as it's parent element. I've figured out that I could give it the right size if I changed the size of every element in between to a 100% size;

```
.panel-first-child {height: 100%;}
.panel-grid-cell {height: 100%;}
.textwidget {height: 100%;}
.embed-responsive {height: 100%;}

<div class="panel-grid-cell" id="pgc-6-1-0" >
<div class="so-panel widget widget_text panel-first-child panel-last-child" id="panel-6-1-0-0" data-index="3">
<h3 class="widget-title">Het Weer</h3>          
<div class="textwidget">
<p class="embed-responsive embed-responsive-16by9" style="padding-bottom: 56.25%;">
<iframe src="http://www.weeronline.nl/Go/ExternalWidgetsNew/ThreeDaysCity?gid=4057381&sizeType=1&temperatureScale=Celsius&defaultSettings=False" height="300px" noscroll="true"></iframe>
</p>
</div>
</div>
</div>
```

The code above works, but it's messy. I'd like to know if there's a way to do this by applying a height setting to only one element.

Comment: Are you trying to apply the style to the contents of the iframe? or just make the iframe itself 100%?  would ".embed-responsive iframe {height:100%}" work?

Comment: In it's current state, the iframe is being cut off at the bottom. I want to allow it's height to become as big as the parent element's size. However, the elements in between mess things up for me, as I need to set `height: 100%;` to each element.

Comment: I think what you're looking for is somehow removing all the bottom margins of all the elements leading up to the iframe.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like an ideal situation for [child selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Child_selectors).  Something along the lines of this though you would likely want to change your `<p>` to a `<div>`:

```
.panel-grid-cell, .panel-grid-cell > div {
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

u can group element or if u can use > * from parent  hope this help :)

```
   .panel-first-child,
   .panel-grid-cell,
   .textwidget,
   .embed-responsive {
     height: 100%;
   }
```

or

```
   .parent > * {height: 100%;}
```